# Why is Visual Studio 2019 UWP XAML Designer showing a blank screen?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I am trying out UWP, so I downloaded the Windows BuildCast UWP test app, and was trying it out but was completely unable to use the XAML Designer! Below is the error (as an image)
[image: Image of the Exception]
and as text ~

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpSurfaceDesigner.Views.UwpIsolatedImageHost.UwpVisualWrapper.CreateWindowCore()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlSurfaceDesigner.Views.DisabledHwndHolder.CreateHandle()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpSurfaceDesigner.Views.UwpIsolatedImageHost.UwpVisualWrapper..ctor(IntPtr parentHwnd, IDCompositionDevice device, UwpSurfaceProcessDocument document, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpSurfaceDesigner.Views.UwpIsolatedImageHost.UwpHwndHost.CreateSurfaceHwnd(IntPtr parentHwnd)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlSurfaceDesigner.Views.IsolatedSurfaceImageHost.IsolatedHwndHost.BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(DependencyObject doTarget, DependencyObject doAncestor, DependencyObject doOldParent)
   at System.Windows.PresentationSource.OnVisualAncestorChanged(DependencyObject uie, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisualAncestorChanged(Object sender, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(Visual child)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.set_Child(UIElement value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlSurfaceDesigner.Views.IsolatedSurfaceImageHost.<CreateSurfaceAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

System.AggregateException
One or more errors occurred.
```

I've tried a few things -

1. Visual Studio Installer -> Repair
2. Checking for Environmental Variables (HPD or MCD)
3. Running VS as Administrator
4. Trying to get VS from Preview channel to test this out
5. Restarting Visual Studio after toggling `Show XAML Designer`
6. Changing the Target Versions to at least 3 different versions


   EDIT: I tried with a new blank UWP C# app, and got this error 
   [image: Image for error #2]

Comment: Please try to open the solution configuration manager and edit the platform as x86 or x64, then rebuild the solution again.

Comment: Already did that quite a few times to no avail